# AngularJS How to watch offset top position of elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to watch offset top position (of each element) and if the distance to top screen border lower than 100 px, i need to hide this div. (each div can move on page). Help please write Angular directive.

I can't watch each element top offset.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.app.directive('blah', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.show();
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return element.offset().top > 120
      }, function(outOfBorder) {
        if (outOfBorder) {
          element.hide()
          console.log(outOfBorder)
        } else {
          element.show()
          console.log(outOfBorder)
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.all {
height: 100px;
width: 300px;
 border:1px solid;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.elements {
height: 30px;
width: 300px;
 border:1px solid red;
float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="all" ng-app="app">
<div class="elements" blah></div>
<div class="elements" blah></div>
<div class="elements" blah></div>
<div class="elements" blah></div>
<div class="elements" blah></div>
<div class="elements" blah></div>
<div class="elements" blah></div>
<div class="elements" blah></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide us with some code of what you've already tried, just asking us to write a directive for you without any effort on your side isn't gonna do much good

Comment: i can't do nothing (

Answer (score 2):

You simply add a watcher with a function (not tested + probably need some renaming):

```
angular.module('blah').directive('blah', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return element.offset().top < 100
      }, function(outOfBorder) {
        if (outOfBorder) {
          element.hide()
        } else {
          element.show()
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The reason why your code is not working is that value you passed to a `$watch` is evaluated before `$watch` is executed. As a result, you watch top offset on the element at the time link is executed - this is a constant number.

EDIT:

If your elements are not absolutely positioned, calling hide will cause all the remaining elements to move up which eventually will make all elements hidden. In this case use `element.addClass('invisible')` and `element.removeClass('invisible')` instead of hiding and showing and define css class as:

```
.invisible { visibility: hidden; }
```

Changed visibility will not affect other element position.

Comment: Thank you! But now all elements are hidden.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(outOfBorder)` before the if statement in a callback. If you get all trues, do the same for `element.offset().top` in a watched function.

Comment: i nave no idea, solution doesn't work. Perhaps, the problem in ng-repeat, that repeat div elems?

Comment: Have you run any of the steps mentioned above?

Comment: yeah, i've got (true, false,true,false ...etc)

Comment: Oh, I think I know the issue. If elements are not absolutely positioned, hiding one element will move the remaining elements up, causing them to disappear as well. Instead of hiding them, try add a class  to the element and define this class css to be `visibility: hidden;`.

Comment: But if element is absolutely positioned?